# Error in select record from sqlite table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table in SQLITE:

```
CREATE TABLE "INVENTORY" (
    "product" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    "version" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    "productionDate" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "order" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "AA" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    "quantity" INTEGER,
    "location" INTEGER,
    "barcode" VARCHAR,   
    PRIMARY KEY ("product", "version", "productionDate", "AA", "order")
);
```

and when I try to select a record (its exists):

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY 
WHERE (product='25120171' AND version='02' AND productionDate='091014' AND AA='001' AND order='4420')
```

I get an error

> SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: SELECT * FROM INVENTORY  WHERE
>   (product='25120171' AND version='02' AND productionDate='091014' AND
>   AA='001' AND order='4420') [ near "order": syntax error ] Exception
>   Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE Exception Message: Component returned failure
>   code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

If i delete `AND order='4420'` from select query:

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY 
    WHERE (product='25120171' AND version='02' AND productionDate='091014' AND AA='001');
```

it works. I can't find where is the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using order as a column name is probably what leads to the error.

[As the doc says](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

> The SQL standard specifies a huge number of keywords which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object. The list of keywords is so long that few people can remember them all. For most SQL code, your safest bet is to never use any English language word as the name of a user-defined object.

`order` is one of them.

You could re-write your query to escape the column name:

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY 
WHERE (product='25120171' AND version='02' AND productionDate='091014' AND AA='001' AND `order`='4420')
```